# Exportar datos a un archivo dxf o dwg

Tags: c#

Buen día.
Tengo una aplicación en la que con un láser mido las dimensiones del marco de una puerta, tengo las posiciones x,y de cada punto sensado.
Necesito que estos datos se exporten a un archivo dfx o dwg para autocad, ya que otra maquina va a fabricar la puerta especifica para ese marco medido, el problema es que no encuentro nada para poder crear el archivo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías mirarte [la documentación sobre el formato DXF](https://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf), que no es muy compleja para lo que planteas y que tu aplicación escriba directamente el fichero. También puedes partir de algún código existente. Una búsqueda por internet te llevará a descubrir algunos ejemplos ([uno](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156522/DXF-Import-NET-Read-and-View-AutoCAD-Format-Files), [dos](https://sandeepjhadotnet.blogspot.com/2016/04/create-dxf-file-using-cdrawing-shapes.html), ...)

Aunque una buena opción (por rápida y simple) es recurrir a una librería externa para que realice el trabajo como **netDXF**, que puedes incorporar a tu proyecto vía [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/netDXF/).